# Why is the answer $0$ for the limit of this function?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I know the answer of the following question is $0$, however I do not understand how this is possible due do the fact that you have $0$ in the denominator of $\arctan(x)$ which means it is undefined at $(0,0)$.

$${\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0) }} \tan\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right)$$

Comment: note that $\arctan$ is bounded and $\tan$ part goes to $0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh so would it be because as $x$ and $y$ in $(\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}})$ go to $0$, the function goes to infinity, and as $arctan$ approaches infinity, it goes to pi/2?

Comment: yes! you are right. In the particular case the other factor tends to $0$ so that I don't care for the limit of $\arctan$. I just care for the fact that it is bounded. But yes if the question is for function $f(x, y) = (1 + \tan(x^{2} + y^{2}))\arctan(1/(x^{2} + y^{2}))$ then I see that it tends to $(1 + 0)\cdot\pi/2 = \pi/2$.

Comment: For all sufficiently small $|x|$ we have $\cos z>1/2.$ And we always have $|\sin z|\leq |z|$. So for all sufficiently small $z=\sqrt {x^2+y^2}\;|$ we have  $|\tan z|\cdot |\arctan (1/z)|\leq (|x|/(1/2))\cdot (\pi /2)\leq \pi |z|.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note we have:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}x^2+y^2=0$$

And consequently:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}=\infty$$

(Because the denominator is always positive, the limit exists. If it was $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{1}{x+y}$, the limit would be undefined.

So $$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\tan(x^2+y^2)=\tan(0)=0$$

And so $$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\arctan(t)=\frac{\pi}2$$

Since both limits exist:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\tan(x^2+y^2)\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)=\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\tan(x^2+y^2) \cdot \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

And evaluating, we get:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\tan(x^2+y^2) \cdot \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)=0\cdot\frac{\pi}2=0$$

Obviously this relies on intuition more than rigor, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what Paramanand helped me figure out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The arctan approaches $\pi/2$
and the tan approaches zero
so their product approaches zero.